# ZPL command length limit?

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

I am generating ZPL command string and the printer (ZT410) does not print all the labels sent. I simply loop through the following code and send the string to the printer (via the IP address on port 9100). Each loop contains a unique set of data where row['item_desc'],row['our_part_number'], and part number change each iteration (so I am not just trying to print 522 identical labels).

```
command += '^XA';
command += '^LT23';
command += '^FO125,30';
command += '^A0N,85,50';        
command += '^FB950,1,,C'        
command += '^FD'+row['item_desc']+'^FS';
command += '^FO20,260';
command += '^A0N,50,50';        
command += '^FD'+part_number+'^FS';
command += '^FO122,260';
command += '^A0N,50,50';        
command += '^FB950,1,,C'        
command += '^FD'+row['our_part_number']+'^FS';
command += '^FO935,255';
command += '^A0N,25,25';        
command += '^FB200,2,,R'        
command += '^FDMy Company Name Phone_Number   ^FS';
command += '^FO'+margin+',105';
command += '^BY3';
command += '^B3N,N,144,N,N';    
command += '^FD'+row['our_part_number']+'^FS';
command += '^XZ';
```

My test lot is 522 labels.  Before adding the company info and barcode, the printer printed all 522 labels, but with the code above, it only prints 485 labels.

Where is the limit?  Is there a limit on the string length that can be sent to the port?  Should I add a carriage return and line feed after each label (so the printer knows where to break the string)?  Or is there a IP:port timeout?

The printer prints the labels, but doesn't respond in any way to the port that sent the command.  If I break the labels into individual command strings and send them sequentially without pause, the printer didn't print ANY labels. Is it possible to query the printer to know when to send the next command string?

*Normally, I would just experiment with trial and error, but in this case that method is expensive and wasteful...*

Comment: Maybe printer buffer is overloaded if you send each label separately? Try add some time out e.g. after 100 labels. Try use parameters and store template in printer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
^PQ522
```

as a command before the ^XZ.

I'd suggest you only send it once though. Sending it 522 times (or even 485 times) might just be a tad wasteful.

Comment: I don't understand what that would do.  All the labels are unique.

Comment: There's no indication that the labels are unique. You mean that you change description on each label? You'd need to explain the detail of your label batches a little more.

Comment: I've added to my question a better outline of what is going on in each loop.

Comment: The printer should start printing on receipt of a `^XZ`. You appear to be saying that you used to be able to print a complete batch of 522 non-identical labels but after changes this is now 485. It's very odd to produce batches of non-identical item labels in thsi manner as one error would lead to products being mislabelled *en masse*. You also say that if you send individual command strings, the printer prints **no** labels. Are you sure that you are not sending ^XA*many labels*^XZ which would fail to print if the ^XZ is missing? This behaviour seems quite bizarre - not "by the book".

Comment: What did I have in my coffee this morning?  ^XA*many labels*^XZ would of course simply overlay all, so that's rubbish. Nevertheless, `^XZ` should trigger printing. I'm confused by the `prints 485 where 522 epected` vs `prints no labels` scenario.

Comment: When I sent single labels, I opened a new connection each time and got a few different connection errors over the course of sending the 522.  I must have jammed up the printers internal que to the point it wouldn't print. I could try using the same connection and slowing down the rate at which I send each label. Surely there is a preferred method or structure I should be using...

Comment: Sorry - I can't duplicate your setup. My connections have always been direct and hence most likely they rely on hardware handshaking.

Answer (score 0):

Use FN fields and save the label locally on the printer(using ^DF), then just call the label and populate the dynamic data in the FN fields